# Destroying jQuery TreeTable instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, treetable

This seems like a simple question, but I'm not how to go about it.

I'm using ludo's great [jquery treetable plugin](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples), however, I want to be able destroy it on call.

Does anyone know how to destroy an instance of this (at least on the javascript side?)

Here are some [examples](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#examples) (I'm using the basic expandable option).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so it's really really simple:

The method is:

```
$('.element').treetable('destroy');
```

Unfortunately, I had to find this out through trial and error, as it's documented nowhere (I can find).

Hope this helps somebody.